# Lucene: filtering by a set of allowed values on a numeric stored field

Tags: java, lucene

Is there a simple way to apply the following filter query:

```
userAccessibleDocTypesSet.contains(doc.type)
```

where the set is passed to the query (with scattered integers), and doc.type is a stored int field on the documents.
A BooleanQuery with a should-clause for all values in the set seems overkill, and might push the limits.

What would be the right approach? How to apply this filter last, for the case when it doesn't filter anything due to full access rights for the user?

Comment: maybe custom score (CustomScoreQuery / CustomScoreProvider) to set the maximum score if doc.type presence is Set + min score filter

Comment: is it one doc type per document or several?

Comment: A single value per document, up to 200 variations. I'm reading about DocValues, but find no documentation for mortals about how to write a query based on them.

Comment: 200 variantions are not a contra indication against should-clauses. Did you make a performance test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with. If you see any performance concerns, please let me know.

```
public class FilterByIntegerSetQuery extends Query
{
    protected String numericDocValueFieldName;
    protected Set<Integer> allowedValues;


    public FilterByIntegerSetQuery(String numericDocValueFieldName, Set<Integer> allowedValues)
    {
        this.numericDocValueFieldName = numericDocValueFieldName;
        this.allowedValues = allowedValues;
    }

    @Override
    public Weight createWeight(IndexSearcher searcher, boolean needsScores)
    {
        return new RandomAccessWeight(this)
        {
            @Override
            protected Bits getMatchingDocs(LeafReaderContext context) throws IOException
            {
                final int len = context.reader().maxDoc();
                final NumericDocValues values = context.reader().getNumericDocValues(numericDocValueFieldName);
                return new Bits()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean get(int index)
                    {
                        return allowedValues.contains((int) values.get(index));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int length()
                    {
                        return len;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public String toString(String field)
    {
        return "(filter "+numericDocValueFieldName+" by set)";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you make a performance comparison with a Or-Query solution? I would expact that after some usages the OS-file-cache will hide the implementation differences.

Comment: There would be so many OR-clauses that I never wanted to go that way. Just putting the Query together would take time. I get <0.01s responses with this one for 200k documents.